# Vaadin 10, how can I add the css class to div element in Java?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin10

I am trying to create a user list in UI cards like this,

```
<style type="text/css">
    .userbox {
        left: 36px;
        color: black;
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-weight: 600;
        width: 300px;
        height: 150px;
        text-indent: 30px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    }

    .userbox:hover {
        background-color: #d1e7cd;
    }

    img {
        border-radius: 5%;
    }
</style>
```

I want to generate these HTML elements dynamically,

```
<div class="userbox"></div>
```

How can I do that? I tried to create Div objects and add the styles but I couldn't find a way in Vaadin Flow.

Answer (score 3):

This should be enough:

```
Div div = new Div();
div.setClassName("userbox");
```

Comment: I think `div.getClassList().add("userbox")` should also work.

Comment: [`setClassName`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/10.0.4/com/vaadin/flow/component/HasStyle.html#setClassName-java.lang.String-)?  Or did you mean [`addClassName`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/10.0.4/com/vaadin/flow/component/HasStyle.html#addClassName-java.lang.String-)? The first wipes out all existing style names, to be replaced by your one and only style name, likely ruining the component’s presentation within a layout. The second adds your given style name alongside any existing style names.

Answer (score 1):

Div implemented HasStyle interface that interface has addClassName("") method:

> `public class Div extends HtmlContainer`
>   `public class HtmlContainer extends HtmlComponent`
>   `public class HtmlComponent extends Component implements HasSize, HasStyle`

```
public interface HasStyle extends HasElement {

    /**
     * Adds a CSS class name to this component.
     *
     * @param className
     *            the CSS class name to add, not <code>null</code>
     */
    default void addClassName(String className) {
        getClassNames().add(className);
    }
```

In my case eclipse doesn't suggest it.

You can use it: 
divElement.addClassName("userbox");